# Second Python Method not being called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginer in Python. I prepared the below script to stop and start a windows service named Jenkins. When I run this, the second method() i.e. start_service() is not executed. Please help...

Below is the script-

```
import os
import win32serviceutil

class RestartServices(object):

    serviceName = 'Jenkins'

    def stop_service(self):
        if win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus(self.serviceName)[1] == 1:
            print('Service ' + self.serviceName + ' is already stopped.')
        elif win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus(self.serviceName)[1] == 4:
            win32serviceutil.StopService(self.serviceName)
            print('Service ' + self.serviceName + ' has been stopped.')

    def start_service(self):
        if win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus(self.serviceName)[1] == 4:
            print('Service ' + self.serviceName + ' is already running')
        elif win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus(self.serviceName)[1] == 1:
            win32serviceutil.StartService(self.serviceName)
            print('Service ' + self.serviceName + ' has been started...')

obj = RestartServices()
obj.stop_service()
obj.start_service()
```

Comment: How do you know its not running? maybe non of your conditions are true, so no prints appear?

Comment: @JLev When the service is in running mode, it only runs the stop_service() method and stops the services. After that is should run start_service() method, but it does not do that.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Try printing the value of the QueryServiceStatus in the first line of start_service. Do you see it? What is the value?

Comment: @JLev It prints- (16, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Well, you can see that the method is called. Now figure out what the value 3 means to you...

Comment: @JLev Now it make sense to me. Thanks buddy :) But Still I am confused in print(win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus(self.serviceName)[1]). Sometimes it returns 1, sometime 2, sometime 3 and 4... Can't figure out what are the correct codes for service state?